# validation on email / postcode fields in sql/oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, constraints

Would be gratefull for some advice on the following - Is it possible to validate email and postcode fields through some kind of check constraint in the sql in oracle ? or this kind of thing as i suspect pl/sql with regular expressions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only concerned with the US, there are several sources of zip codes that you can obtain in flat-file format and import into a table, and then apply a foreign key constraint in your addresses to that table.

Email addresses can be matched against a regular expression (needs 10g or higher) to validate the format, but checking to see if they are actual addresses is a much more difficult task.

Comment: thanks, thats helpful - i just came across some oracle info which ties in with your 10g or higher reg expression check tip - http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/webcolumns/2003/techarticles/rischert_regexp_pt2.html

Comment: @oej the link above has been removed

Answer (score 8):

Here's the regexp syntax for an email address, including quotes

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'
```

So you can use regexp_like() in a where clause or regexp_substr() to check whether your field contains a valid email address.  Here's an example-you'll see that the regexp_substr() returns NULL on the address missing the .domain, which fails the substring validation.  From there you can build a check constraint around it, or enforce it using a trigger(yuck), etc.

```
SQL> desc email
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMAIL_ID                                           NUMBER
 EMAIL_ADDRESS                                      VARCHAR2(128)


SQL> select * from email;

  EMAIL_ID EMAIL_ADDRESS
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 NEIL@GMAIL.COM
         2 JOE@UTAH.GOV
         3 lower_name@lower.org
         4 bad_address@missing_domaindotorg


SQL> @qry2
SQL> column email_address format a40
SQL> column substr_result format a30
SQL> SELECT  email_address
  2       ,  regexp_substr(email_address,'[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}') substr_result
  3    FROM  email
  4  /

EMAIL_ADDRESS                            SUBSTR_RESULT
---------------------------------------- ------------------------------
NEIL@GMAIL.COM                           NEIL@GMAIL.COM
JOE@UTAH.GOV                             JOE@UTAH.GOV
lower_name@lower.org                     lower_name@lower.org
bad_address@missing_domaindotorg
```

Using the same data, here is a query which limits only valid email addresses, using REGEXP_LIKE

```
SQL> column email_address format a40
SQL> column substr_result format a30
SQL> SELECT  email_address
  2    FROM  email
  3   WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (email_address, '[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}');

EMAIL_ADDRESS
----------------------------------------
NEIL@GMAIL.COM
JOE@UTAH.GOV
lower_name@lower.org
```

Search the contents page of the [SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm) for regexp to see the regular expression support.

Comment: That regexp won't work for email addresses that use the .museum and .travel TLDs.

Comment: counsel@Lawrence@Andrea.com passes this regular expression, and should not

Answer (score 6):

an even better regular expression is:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

(same expression given but anchored to start (`^`) and end (`$`) of line)

without the anchors, expressions like 'test1@hotmail.com some other text'
would be validated and, if you are trying to validate one email, 
the above string should not validate

Note: the email should be previously trimmed so that leading or trailing spaces
won't screw up validation.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 2):

Be careful at the `'.'` character: this is a joker (like `*` or `%` in SQL syntax).
You must excape it with `'\'`.

Here is the regexp I use to match [RFC2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) (maybe not all cases :)):

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%''\*\+-/=\?^_`\{|\}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you can use a regex to validate the emails but with limited accuracy. You may find it better to use a service like [Real Email](https://isitarealemail.com) to validate the emails, which not only checks if the email looks correct, but if the domain and account are valid.

You could export your data as a csv then validate it. For more see [How to validate emails in an sql database](https://docs.isitarealemail.com/how-to-validate-email-addresses-in-an-sql-database).

Answer (score -1):

```
declare

-- where customer is the table in my case

email_input customer.email%type;

begin

    email_input:=:EMAIL; 
    IF email_input is not null
    AND email_input not like '%@%.COM' then
        message('Please enter a valid email address!');
        message('   ');
        clear_message;
        :EMAIL:=null;
        raise form_trigger_failure;
    end if;
end;
```