# Regexp_like vs regex validators online - diferent results

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, email-validation

I have a regex expression for email validation using plsql that is giving me some headaches... :)
This is the condition I'm using for an email (rercear12345@gmail.com) validation:

```
IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (user_email, '^([\w\-\.]+)@((\[([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([\w\-]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))$') THEN
            control := FALSE;
            dbms_output.put_line('EMAIL '||C.user_email||' not according to regex');
END IF;
```

If I make a select based on the expression I don't get any values either:

```
Select * from TABLE_X where REGEXP_LIKE (user_email, '^([\w\-\.]+)@((\[([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([\w\-]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))$');
```

Using regex101.com I get full match with this email: rercear12345@gmail.com

Any idea?

Comment: It seems that every implementation of regular expressions is different. I'm not sure if Oracle supports Perl-style backslash classes in a character-class bracket expression - you may have to use the equivalent Posix character classes (e.g. [:alnum:] instead \w). You don't mention which version of Oracle you're using - 11g's regular expression support is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm#g1015343).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression syntax that Oracle supports is [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html#GUID-969230D6-FC1A-4C75-BF2A-6B1BE909DED6).

It seems Oracle doesn't understand the `\w` inside the `[]`. You can expand that to:

```
with table_x (user_email) as (
  select 'rercear12345@gmail.com' from dual
  union all
  select 'bad name@gmail.com' from dual
)
Select * from TABLE_X
where REGEXP_LIKE (user_email, '^[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+@((\[([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\])|([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$');

USER_EMAIL            
----------------------
rercear12345@gmail.com
```

You don't need to escape the `.` or `-` inside the square brackets, by doing that you would allow literal backslashes to be matched.

This sort of requirement has come up before - e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/788892/266304) - but you seem be allowing IP address octets instead of FQDNs, enclosed in literal square brackets, which is unusual.

As @BobJarvis said you could also use the `[:alnum:]` but would still need to include underscore. That could allow non-ASCII 'letter' characters you aren't expecting; though they may be valid, [as are other symbols you exclude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax); you seem to be following the 'common advice' mentioned in that article though.

Comment: That solved the problem. Using your suggestion I removed the escape from the . in another column validation rule for values as "Av. do Céu" using ^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.ãáàéèêíìóòúùÃÁÀÉÈÊÍÌÓÒÚÙ]+$ instead of ^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.ãáàéèêíìóòúùÃÁÀÉÈÊÍÌÓÒÚÙ]+$ but I get a similar situation.

Comment: @Eunito - I don't think `\s` would be recognised by Oracle there either. Maybe `[[:alnum:][:space:]].` would replace all of that, depending on your character set?

Comment: used [:space:] instead of \s and worked... hmm the problem seems to be the escape as you mentioned! Thank you!

Comment: Good. [:alnum:] might handle all those accented characters and simplify things a bit.